# hash with array as a key, how to fetch by fist value in the hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, group-by, fetch

I have a grouped hash created with a group_by which creates an Array as a key:

```
 @lines.group_by{|e| [e.activity, e.subactivity]}
```

Therefore, my resultant hash looks like this one:

```
{[7, 6]=>
  [{:field_one=>"AAA",
    :field_two=>"BBB",
    :activity=>7,
    :subactivity=>6}],
 [1,0] =>
  [{:field_one=>"CCC",
    :field_two=>"DDD",
    :activity=>1,
    :subactivity=>0}],
 [1,7] =>
  [{:field_one=>"EEE",
    :field_two=>"FFF",
    :activity=>1,
    :subactivity=>7}],
}
```

I would like to get an array with all the values for keys such as `[1, *]`. So, the result would be:

```
  [{:field_one=>"CCC",
    :field_two=>"DDD",
    :activity=>1,
    :subactivity=>0},
   {:field_one=>"EEE",
    :field_two=>"FFF",
    :activity=>1,
    :subactivity=>7}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Should the key include 1 or should the first element of the key == 1?

Comment: Note that the answers could have been simplified you prefaced your hash with `h = `. That way, readers could reference `h` in answers and comments without having to define it. When giving examples, it is helpful to assign variables to all input objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h.select { |(f,_),v| f==1 }.values
```

or

```
h.values_at(*h.keys.select { |f,_| f==1 })
```

If the keys were arrays of one or more elements, possibly varying in size, but you were only concerned with the first element (as here), you would write:

```
h.select { |(f,*_),v| f==1 }.values
```

or just

```
h.select { |(f,*),v| f==1 }.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will helps.

**Input**

```
h = {
  [7, 6] =>
    [
      {:field_one => "AAA",
       :field_two => "BBB",
       :activity => 7,
       :subactivity => 6}
    ],
  [1, 0] =>
    [
      {:field_one => "CCC",
       :field_two => "DDD",
       :activity => 1,
       :subactivity => 0}
    ],
  [1, 7] =>
    [
      {:field_one => "EEE",
       :field_two => "FFF",
       :activity => 1,
       :subactivity => 7}
    ],
}
```

**code**:

```
h.keys.group_by { |a| a[0] }.each_with_object({}) do |(k, keys), exp| 
  exp[k] = keys.map { |key| h[key] }.flatten 
end
```

**output**

```
{
  7 => [
    {:field_one => "AAA", :field_two => "BBB", :activity => 7, :subactivity => 6}
  ],
  1 => [
    {:field_one => "CCC", :field_two => "DDD", :activity => 1, :subactivity => 0},
    {:field_one => "EEE", :field_two => "FFF", :activity => 1, :subactivity => 7}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any key can include the number `1` then use `#include?`:

```
vals.select { |k, _v| k.include?(1) }.values.flatten
=> [{:field_one=>"CCC", :field_two=>"DDD", :activity=>1, :subactivity=>0}, {:field_one=>"EEE", :field_two=>"FFF", :activity=>1, :subactivity=>7}]
```

Or if the first value in the key must be a `1` then:

```
vals.select { |k, _v| k[0] == 1 }.values.flatten
=> [{:field_one=>"CCC", :field_two=>"DDD", :activity=>1, :subactivity=>0}, {:field_one=>"EEE", :field_two=>"FFF", :activity=>1, :subactivity=>7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose h is your hash, then:

```
arr = []
h.each do |k,v|
   arr << v if k.first == 1
end
```